# Can I use laravel octane with swoole for production?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laravel-octane

my laravel website is already using ngnix + php-fpm, it is working fine, but I want to migrate to docker with octane, do you know a good tutorial to check it? Octane uses swoole or roadrunner, then this means that it is no required nginx? I mean nginx inside the docker container. thanks.

Comment: [Laravel Octane with Swoole](https://openswoole.com/article/laravel-octane-with-swoole)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial but it is not what I am searching for